# ansible and npm throw permission denied error

Tags: git, npm, ansible

When running ansible playbook (as `root`) which runs `npm` command to install a module from a git repository, I get `Permission denied` error for dir `/root/tmp/..`

Here's the full error from `npm`:

```
11 verbose stack Error: exited with error code: 128
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/util/finished.js:12:19)
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
11 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
11 verbose stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
11 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
11 verbose stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
12 verbose cwd /root/tmp
13 verbose Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
14 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git"
15 verbose node v10.14.1
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error Error while executing:
17 error /bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
17 error
17 error fatal: Cannot change to '/root/tmp/..': Permission denied
17 error
17 error exited with error code: 128
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here's the Ansible playbook:

```
- name: top-name
  hosts: myhost

  tasks:  
  - name: task-name
    become: true
    environment:
      PATH: /usr/local/bin:/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}
    command: npm i git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
    args:
      chdir: /root/tmp
    register: out
```

Root should not have permission denied errors.
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write to the root folder while your user is not root

```
17 error fatal: Cannot change to '/root/tmp/..': Permission denied
```

Change the folder herE:

```
args:
  chdir: /root/tmp
```

Change it to `/tmp` instead of `root/tmp`

Comment: The user should be root due to `become: true`. The default user in this case is `root`.
There seems to be problem specifically with `npm` using git repositories. Running `npm i randompackage` installs everything properly without any permission issues.
When I change the dir to `/tmp`, the command just hangs. I suspect it waits to answer the git's `known_hosts` question even though it has been answered before and even though running command `/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git` through ansible task works fine :)
Not sure where to move from here. Kind of stuck :/

Answer (score 0):

recently I've had a similar issue. I learnt that this:

```
...
  command: "npm install"
  args:
    chdir: "/mydir"
```

And this:

```
...
  command: "npm install /mydir"
```

are not the same.
The first one throws an "access denied" message, the second one works. I don't understand why but I hope it helps.